# How does one enforce HTTP responses as JSON messages?

Tags: json, http

I am quite new to json and webservices.

I have a question which might as well be a dumb one but I have not been able to find an answer.

Lets say I have a html `form` which performs a GET method on submission.
The server performs an HTTP response.

How does one make sure that the content(body) of the response is in JSON format?

-V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a vague question as I don't know what your server is doing and replying (obviously it should be in the JSON format response) but you should also include a `Content-type` HTTP header as shown below so the browser knows it is receiving JSON:

```
Content-type: application/json
```

Your JSON response should look like this (taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)):

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "age": 25,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY",
        "postalCode": 10021
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "212 555-1234"
        },
        {
            "type": "fax",
            "number": "646 555-4567"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data=response_from_the_page;
try {
json = $.parseJSON(data);
} catch (e) {
// not json
}
```